# XSL flatten with inherit

Tags: xslt

I want to flatten an XML document such that every element would copy the attributes of its parent and convert `<span/>` into `<text/>`
**Input:**

```
<el value="
    <span bold="true">
        one
        <span italics="true">
            two
            <span superscript="true">
                three
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span subscript="true">
        four
    </span>
"/>
```

**Output:**

```
<text bold="true">one</text>
<text bold="true" italics="true">two</text>
<text bold="true" italics="true" superscript="true">three</text>
<text subscript="true">four</text>
```

I've tried using `copy-of` with `..` but that obviously only copies one level up from the input. I presume I need a variable but I am unsure of how to operate on it - it doesn't seem like I can do `<xsl:value-of select="$text-element"><!--call template--></xsl:value-of>`. The fact that this is a string inside an attribute doesn't help either...

Comment: The input is not an XML document. -- See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445105/3016153

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help, once you make the XML well-formed:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::*/@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </text>
</xsl:template>
```